# Build with SP Designer 2007, package with VStudio 2008

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, visual-studio

This is for a MOSS 2007 portal. I need to add a web part page to a WSS site. I would like to brand the page using SharePoint Designer 2007, but not save to site directly since that results in customized (or unghosted) copy of the page, i.e. get saved to the content database. Rather, I want to keep that page ghosted since it will go on every site, so I would like to add it to the file system of the front-end web server. Can I build the page in Designer 2007 and package the page and its resources and deploy it as a feature using Visual Studio 2008?

Googled and did not uncover much. Decided to check with the experts here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you create this page in development environment and upload to the required environment using feature(module element). Any site, where you activate the feature the page is uploaded into the set library/folder.

Comment: So I can create this page in say, a dev/staging environment first? Does the page get saved in the content database and not the file system? In that case, how do I copy the file to package it in a feature based WSP?

Comment: Yes, you can create the page in dev/staging. The page would be created in the content database(pages library or some document library) and you need to download the page for packaging as a feature.